# g++ creates several symbols of a const?

Tags: c++, gcc

In one of my header (C++) files I changed

```
   #define TIMEOUT 10
```

to the more(?) C++ way:

```
const int TIMEOUT = 10;
```

It seems however, g++(v 4.4.3) now includes this symbol several times in the binary.

```
$ nm -C build/ipd/ipd |head
08050420 T ToUnixTime
08050470 T ParseTime
080504c0 T ParseISOTime
080518e4 r TIMEOUT
080518ec r TIMEOUT
080518f4 r TIMEOUT
080518fc r TIMEOUT
080503e0 T HandleMessage
```

How come ?

Comment: I think the more more C++ way would be `static const int TIMEOUT = 10;`

Comment: @John Dibling: No. `const` objects in C++ have internal linkage by default. `static` will not have any effect.

Answer (score 6):

You have probably included your header in four separate translation units (.cpp files).

Namespace-scope const variables not declared `extern` are implicitly `static`, so there will be one for each translation unit in which the header is included.

Comment: So, should I rather just keep the #define ?

Comment: @nissen:  If you really want exactly one copy, declare it `extern` in the header and then define it in exactly one cpp file, or for integer constants use the enumeration trick that Potatoswatter shows in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try an `enum` instead. It's much like a `#define`, you can't take a reference to it, and it's guaranteed not to take any space anywhere.

```
enum { TIMEOUT = 10 };
```

But if it's not causing you any trouble, I wouldn't worry about it one way or another. The `const int` way is just fine and we're talking about 16 bytes, give or take.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler may have found that copying the symbol is more efficient than referencing it.  This is due to the `const` modifier.

In many instances, loading a register with an "immediate" value (one stored in the executable) is more efficient than loading from a location in ROM (Read Only Memory), which uses indirect addressing.

I would not worry about duplications of a constant integer in many object files, unless it makes the files too large to fit on the hard drive.  Also, object files are a interim storage for data until the executable or libraries are generated.

I suggest concentrating more on the quality and robustness of your application than the internals of object files.